# CVSNT - unable to checkout, update, retrieve file history, and more

Tags: cvs, cvsnt

We have used CVSNT in our group without issue for years.  Our installation of CVSNT is running on Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition.  We are using CVSNT 2.0.51d and CVS locking service 2.5.05.

Unfortunately, we began to encounter issues with CVS yesterday.  It looks like CVS has an issue that leads to a problem with the CVS locking service.  We get the following error when we try to check out a module, list history for a file, perform a CVS update, etc.  In this example, we see the following error when we do a checkout:

```
Failed to obtain lock on /cvs/MyProject/.myFilename,v: FAIL Unknown flag 'Full'
```

We have five CVS modules.  We see this error when we try to check out any of the five modules.  We didn't do anything unusual lately either.  We did create a CVS branch in one of our modules yesterday as well as our typical commits, but we've created branches before and have completed thousands of checkins.

The CVS ls command does not fail.  Other simple commands do not fail either.  My guess is there's an issue with the locks.  We did try running the CVS lock service in debug mode (cvslock -test) but we did not see any unusual debug messages when we used our CVS client to connect.

We also currently use the pserver method to connect to our CVS server.  When I login to our Windows server - where the CVS server resides - and run a CVS client locally on that server and connect using the local method, the CVS checkout works fine!

Can anyone provide any ideas to help us resolve this issue?

Comment: We are having the same problem and I've tried numerous things to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to cvslock.
The following appeared to resolve the main issue:
* Find and kill cvslock in the task manager
* run 'cvslock -i' as admin
* go into services and make sure cvslock has started.